# Karate framework not getting value return from another feature file

Tags: automation, automated-tests, karate, web-api-testing

I am trying to make a call to another feature file for generating Bearer token and then return that value, My token is getting generated and its printing but i am getting null value returned. I saw similar post and i am doing whats explained in that and also in Karate tutorial. what is wrong here?

token generator feature file

```
 Given path '/as/token.oauth2'
And header Content-Type = 'application/json'
* params { client_id: 'TestScopeClient', response_type: 'token', grant_type: 'client_credentials',client_secret: '2Federate', scope: 'enr.dipor.enr.r clgn.tdw.clgn.r'}
When method Post
Then status 200
* def authToken = response
```

i am calling from below code

Scenario: get all users and then get the first user by id

```
def t = call read('classpath:ReUsableFunctions/AuthToken.feature') 
print 'token return value is '+t
def token = t.token
print 'token return value is '+token
```

console output is below

```
 Secure
{"access_token":"token is generated and printing here","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":35999}

19:46:24.787 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] token return value is [object Object] 
19:46:24.797 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] token return value is null
```

as you can see when i print the token return in the feature file i am getting null

Comment: in my opinion, getting help for such a complicated flow is possible only if you follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - but maybe someone else here can help